# form_for doesn't submit fields to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for, strong-parameters

I've searched and searched and nothing came up, so I need to ask you guys for help.

I have a simple new form that should take two fields from form_for and then post it into database. The problem is it doesn't.

My sample db has only two fields: name and site_id

Here's my new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @kejsu do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.text_field :site_id %>
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the controller:

```
def new
    @kejsu = Kejs.new
end

def create
    @kejsu = Kejs.new(params[:kejsu])
    if @kejsu.save
        redirect_to kejs_index_path
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

After hitting submit button only timestamps are inserted. Here's the snippet from **rails server**:

```
Started POST "/cases" for 192.168.56.1 at 2013-12-10 23:11:03 +0000
Processing by KejsyController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â",         "authenticity_token"=>"Sr2ssiwtRtk9pRT5VfuDFglsEmGnjzwVkRGGBSb2zhA=", "kejs"=>    {"name"=>"aa", "site_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (5.1ms)  INSERT INTO "kejs" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)       [["created_at", Tue, 10 Dec 2013 23:11:03 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Tue, 10 Dec 2013     23:11:03 UTC +00:00]]
   (4.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://192.168.56.101:3000/cases
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 9.2ms)
```

As you can see those fields are passed as parameters, but INSERT doesn't insert them at all.

I've tried it with default restful routing, writing my own routes and it doesn't work either way.

As a bonus my routes:

```
  get 'cases' => 'kejsy#index', as: :kejs_index
  get 'cases/new' => 'kejsy#new', as: :new_kejs
  post 'cases' => 'kejsy#create'
```

Comment: It would be helpful to include model as well. It looks like from log that youur action is receiving parameters correctly and problem is in line Kejsu.new(params[:kejsu])

Comment: My model is pretty empty, just standard declaration created via rails g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params[:kejsu]` reference uses `:kejsu`, but your parameters exist under `params[:kejs]`, so you're picking up `nil` for the value.

The key in `params` is determined by the *class name* of the object passed to `form_for` (i.e. `Kejs` in this case), not by the variable name (i.e. `@kejsu`). If you think about it, this makes sense because the variable name is not even *available* to `form_for`, since the *value* of the `@kejsu` is what is passed.

Comment: That's not the direct answer I was looking for, but you pointed me in a direction what to look for. After doing this small change the Rails screamed at me with `ForbiddenAttributesError` error, so I did a little searching and what came up were "strong parameters". I wasn't aware that Rails 4 (which I'm using) changed the behavior on dealing with parameters. But getting to the point: I used `require` and `permit` on `params` and it worked like a charm. I'll post it as answer.

Comment: :-) I was going to say something about strong parameters, but you said you weren't getting any errors, so I started looking elsewhere.

Comment: I'm very new to rails and I still don't quite understand why I should use `:kejs` and not `:kejsu`. Reading the tutorials I thought that `params[:kejsu]` is the object I'm referencing given in the `<%= form_for @kejsu do |f| %>`, but I guess I got that wrong.

Comment: I'll follow-up on this issue about `params[:kejsu]` since it's associated with the original question, but I'd suggest you treat any question or answer having to do with strong parameters as a _separate_ question/answer, if that's ok.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130630/216381 for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

to debug you can use `render :text => params.inspect` inside your controller so I will change my code like this

```
def create
  render :text => params.inspect
end
```

Now go and sumbit your form. What is name of key inside your params? Is it `kejsu` or `kejs`?

If its `kejs` than you can change your code to

```
def create
  @kejsu = Kejs.new(params[:kejs])

  if @kejsu.save
    redirect_to kejs_index_path
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As promised, the answer with strong parameters:

```
def create
    @kejsu = Kejs.new(kejs_params)

    if @kejsu.save
        redirect_to kejs_index_path
    else
        render "new"
    end
end

def kejs_params
    params.require(:kejs).permit(:name, :site_id)
end
```

I needed to change the way I'm dealing with parameters passed via form by creating new method that permits given fields. Now it works like it supposed to.

Thanks for all the hints.